# Raspberry pi zero for lossless music?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, music, mopidy

I've seen a lot of DIY projects and open source applications for hi-res music players based on the Raspberry Pi.

However, is the raspberry Pi Zero actually powerful enough to to do lossless music playback?

NOTE: I'm not streaming--will likely use Mopidy as the backend music player, then control the player with an MPD app from my phone.

Comment: Yes it is powerful enough.

Comment: @EricF if so, could you submit an answer explaining why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What, exactly, it can play is going to be dependent on the player software and the actual sample rate etc of the audio, but for reference, FLAC losslessly compresses PCM audio.

Redbook audio (CD standard) is uncompressed 16-bit Linear PCM at about 44kHz. Back when internal CD drives were new, they often had headphone jacks and playback controls, and they could easily play CD audio *without being connected to a computer* (one could jumper a bare PSU and power via molex without a computer attached).

Surely this is a very rough approximation, but we are talking about a technology specification from c. 1988. Very little audio needs to be beyond 44 or 48kHz, since human hearing range spans approximately 22kHz. FLAC supports up to 24bit, but 24-bit authoring is not always done for legacy reasons (embedded systems sometimes cannot support it), so 16 bit is sort of a Least Common Denominator.

After decompression, FLAC is PCM (possibly linear or LPCM) probably 16-24 bit and probably 44 to 48kHz. Very similar to Redbook standard by the numbers if not the exact representation.

So the hardware power is not really an issue for playback, but rather for decompression.

I see that the Rasberry Pi Zero has a slightly faster processor than the Raspberry Pi 3, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) says that the RP3 can decode H.265 in software using the CPU (it lacks dedicated H.265 decoding hardware). So I suspect that the CPU is up to the task for 2-channel audio decompression.

Comment: And to put this into perspective: H.265 video decompression requires vastly more CPU power than the most complicated audio compression scheme one could come up with.